# intent filters in query when targeting android 11

Tags: android

i'm using 2 ways for detecting package installed on device

first,

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo pInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        ApplicationInfo aInfo = pInfo.applicationInfo;
        return aInfo.enabled
```

second,

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (intent != null) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        context.startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
    }
```

when I target sdk version 30 above, they return null
so I refered guide about package visibility on [developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring)

and I declared it on manifest like below

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

**It worked but now I wonder what differences between using filter action main like above and QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission**

**I understood that app can be without main action filter. but usual cases it will have, so can the main action filter be alternative of query_all_packages permission?**

Answer (score 0):

You defined wrong action. Try this: (this to open youtube app)

```
<package android:name="com.google.android.youtube" />
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent>
```

And FYI about [`QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility):

> In the rare cases where the  element doesn't provide adequate package visibility, you can use the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. If you publish your app on Google Play, your app's use of this permission is subject to approval based on an upcoming policy.

Comment: hi @huy Nguyen, do you know why setting '<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> lets visibility to other apps? while <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> does not?